# Return True/False if Series of Lists contains all elements of Reference List

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series of lists:

```
s = pd.Series[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4), (8, 9, 10)]
```

I would like to check whether any list in the series contains all elements of a reference list:

```
l = [4, 5]
```

The function would return true based on the 2nd list in the series satisfying the criteria.

Ideas on how to implement this? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
def contains_valid_data():
        return all(x in s for x in l)

def contains_valid_data():
        return set(l).issubset(s)
```

Comment: Figure out *a* way to do this before worrying about the "best" way.

Comment: @chepner I have made an edit thanks to your comment, any direction on my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4), (8, 9, 10)])
l = [4, 5]

def checkList(s, l):
    return s[s.apply(lambda x: len(set(l).intersection(set(x)))== len(l)]

checkList(s, l)
```

```
1    (4, 5, 6)
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the expected output but you can try this :

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [8, 9, 10]])
l = [4, 5]

out = s.apply(lambda x: set(l).issubset(x))

print(out)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Or, if you want to return a unique boolean value, you can use this :

```
def contains_valid_data():
    if (s.apply(lambda x: set(l).issubset(x))==True).any():
        return True

contains_valid_data()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to check if each row contains all the elements in `l` (with a lambda expression or a function) and transform this `pd.Series` into a boolean series first. And then simply use the [`pandas.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) function to aggregate all the boolean values with an `OR` operation.

```py
# s = pd.Series([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4), (8, 9, 10)])
# l = [4, 5]

l = set(l)  # Transform the list into a `set` for better performance. 
is_some_row_containing_l = s.map(lambda ss: set(ss).issuperset(l)).any()
```